# DataFrame with MultiIndex to nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

I have a dataframe with a MultiIndex.

```
             01.01  02.01  03.01  04.01
bar total1     40     52     18     11
    total2     36     85      5     92
baz total1     23     39     45     70
    total2     50     49     51     65
foo total1     23     97     17     97
    total2     64     56     94     45
qux total1     13     73     38      4
    total2     80      8     61     50
```

`df.index.values` results in:

```
array([('bar', 'total1'), ('bar', 'total2'), ('baz', 'total1'),
       ('baz', 'total2'), ('foo', 'total1'), ('foo', 'total2'),
       ('qux', 'total1'), ('qux', 'total2')], dtype=object)
```

I am ultimately looking to transform the dataframe into a dictionary of dictionaries such that the first dict keys are one of `['bar','baz', 'foo','qux']` and values are the dates and the inner dictionary is made of 'total1' and 'totals2' as key and the values are the integers of the df.
Alternative explanation, is for example if `dict1` is the dict then calling `dict1['bar']` would result in the output:

```py
{'bar':{'01.01':{'total1':40,'total2':36},'02.01':{'total1':52,'total2':85},'03.01':{'total1':18,'total2':5},'04.01':{'total1':11,'total2':92} } }
```

How and what would I need to alter in order to achieve this? Is this an indexing issue?

Comment: Did you try `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: @albert yes and `df.to_dict()` results in:                                            `{'01.01': {('bar', 'total1'): 40, ('bar', 'total2'): 36, ('baz', 'total1'): 23, ('baz', 'total2'): 50,`etc..   `df.to_dict('index')` results in: `('bar', 'total1'): {'01.08': 40, '02.08': 52, '03.08': 18, '04.08': 11}, ('bar', 'total2'): {'01.08': 36, '02.08': 85, '03.08': 5, '04.08': 92}`. So it gets me near where I want to be, that's why I thought it might be an issue with the formation of the dataframe.

Comment: You might take a look at the supported options/parameters for `df.to_csv()` since those let you manipulate the way the data is transformed: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html I'd suggest `df.to_csv('index')` but did not try it.

Answer (score 35):

For converting whole dataframe to dictionary Try:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name).to_dict()).to_dict()

{'bar': {'01.01': {'total1': 40, 'total2': 36},
  '02.01': {'total1': 52, 'total2': 85},
  '03.01': {'total1': 18, 'total2': 5},
  '04.01': {'total1': 11, 'total2': 92}},
 'baz': {'01.01': {'total1': 23, 'total2': 50},
  '02.01': {'total1': 39, 'total2': 49},
  '03.01': {'total1': 45, 'total2': 51},
  '04.01': {'total1': 70, 'total2': 65}},
 'foo': {'01.01': {'total1': 23, 'total2': 64},
  '02.01': {'total1': 97, 'total2': 56},
  '03.01': {'total1': 17, 'total2': 94},
  '04.01': {'total1': 97, 'total2': 45}},
 'qux': {'01.01': {'total1': 13, 'total2': 80},
  '02.01': {'total1': 73, 'total2': 8},
  '03.01': {'total1': 38, 'total2': 61},
  '04.01': {'total1': 4, 'total2': 50}}}
```

For converting one particular column, select before converting it to dictionary i.e

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name)[colname].to_dict()).to_dict()
```

Comment: A great answer sir.

Comment: @jezrael its a great answer already. Felt like completing it for future readers.

Comment: I removed the link there.

Comment: I've been looking fo this method for the whole day now. This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

piRSquared's answer is great if the number of groups is small but if there are many groups, it is very slow because `groupby.apply` has to make calls to a Python function many times.<sup>1</sup>

If there are many groups, a faster way to convert a dataframe into a nested dictionary is to simply loop over the dataframe using `itertuples` and construct a dictionary on the fly. Because we need a nested dictionary, `dict.setdefault()` or `collections.defaultdict` will be helpful.

```py
dict2 = {}
for (idx1, idx2), *vals in df.itertuples():
    for col, val in zip(df.columns, vals):
        dict2.setdefault(idx1, {}).setdefault(col, {})[idx2] = val
```

`dict.setdefault()` here is helping us to insert a key with an empty dictionary as a value if it doesn't exist. It produces the same result as the following more verbose code.

```py
dict2 = {}
for (idx1, idx2), *vals in df.itertuples():
    for col, val in zip(df.columns, vals):
        if idx1 in dict2:
            if col in dict2[idx1]:
                dict2[idx1][col][idx2] = val
            else:
                dict2[idx1][col] = {idx2: val}
        else:
            dict2[idx1] = {col: {idx2: val}}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Benchmark to support the claim made above (tested on Python 3.11.5, pandas 2.2.0):

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((range(1000), range(10)))
df = pd.DataFrame({c: range(10000) for c in 'ABCD'}, index=idx)

%%timeit
dict1 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name).to_dict()).to_dict()
# 849 ms ± 11.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
dict2 = {}
for (idx1, idx2), *vals in df.itertuples():
    for col, val in zip(df.columns, vals):
        dict2.setdefault(idx1, {}).setdefault(col, {})[idx2] = val
# 50.3 ms ± 4.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As you can see from the benchmark above if there are 1000 groups, then the straightforward loop is 16 times faster then `groupby.apply` solution. This gap widens as the number of groups increase.

On the other hand, if there are few groups (<10) then both approaches are very fast so performance probably isn't an issue anymore.

More explanation on this point can be explained can be found at [Convert Pandas Dataframe to nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780569/19123103).