# custom nested json structre with different sets

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and pandas have a csv file with

```
.----.---------.-------.-------------------.-------------------.-------------------.-------------------.
| id | country | state | cold_stress_score | cold_stress_level | heat_stress_score | heat_stress_level |
:----+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------:
|  1 | USA     | NJ    |             0.003 | low               |             0.673 | moderate          |
:----+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------:
|  2 | USA     | NJ    |             0.001 | high              |               0.2 | high              |
:----+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------:
|  3 | USA     | NJ    |             0.004 | moderate          |               0.3 | low               |
:----+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------:
|  4 | USA     | NY    |             0.005 | moderate          |               0.4 | moderate          |
:----+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------:
|  5 | USA     | NY    |             0.006 | high              |               0.5 | high              |
:----+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------:
|  6 | USA     | NY    |             0.009 | low               |               0.6 | low               |
'----'---------'-------'-------------------'-------------------'-------------------'-------------------'
```

and i wanted to convert this into nested way of json

expected json

```
  {
  "id":1,
  "country": "USA",
  "state": "NJ",
  "cold_stress":{
    "cold_stress_score" : 0.003,
    "cold_stress_level": "low",
  },
  "heat_stress":{
    "heat_stress_score" : 0.0673,
    "heat_stress_level": "moderate",

  }

}
```

I tried this solution 
[Convert Pandas Dataframe to nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470954/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json)

```
j = (df.groupby(['id','country','state'], as_index=False)
             .apply(lambda x: x[['cold_stress_score','cold_stress_level']].to_dict('r'))
             .reset_index()
             .rename(columns={0:'cold_stress'})
             .to_json(orient='records'))
```

I wanted to add heat Stress to json 
 the above code returning

```
  "id":1,
  "country": "USA",
  "state": "NJ",
  "cold_stress":{
    "cold_stress_score" : 0.003,
    "cold_stress_level": "low",
  }
}
```

how can I able to add heat_stress my csv is too big and am looking for dynamic value populating in above like cold stress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do little or no processing like here, pandas is both overkill and too complex. My advice is to stick to the `csv` and `json` modules from the standard library.

Code could be (more or less):

```
with open(inputfile) as fdin, open (outputfile, "w") as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fdin)
    js = [{'id': int(row['id']), 'country': row['country'], 'state': row['state'],
           'cold_stress': {'cold_stress_code': row['cold_stress_code'],
                           'cold_stress_level': row['cold_stress_level']},  
           'heat_stress': {'heat_stress_code': row['heat_stress_code'],
                           'heat_stress_level': row['heat_stress_level']}, 
           } for row in rd]
    json.dump(js, fdout, indent=2)
```

Comment: i have to do some filters over data like select based on id or state or country , i thought pandas would be best to do more operations and filtering

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```py
# create first grouping (leave heat columns same)
j = (df.groupby(['id','country','state', 'heat_stress_score', 'heat_stress_level'], as_index=False)
             .apply(lambda x: x[['cold_stress_score','cold_stress_level']].to_dict('r'))
             .reset_index()
             .rename(columns={0:'cold_stress'}))
# care about heat grouping
j = (j.groupby(['id','country','state', 'cold_stress'], as_index=False)
             .apply(lambda x: x[['heat_stress_score','heat_stress_level']].to_dict('r'))
             .reset_index()
             .rename(columns={0:'heat_stress'})
             .to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: No its not working it only returning `tide-Data` second one is not coming

Comment: I just checked the documentation of `rename` [see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and adjusted the answer.

Comment: Seems its not working, the code snip i shared is just example i need to add heat_stress as second one but the exaple works for one which is tide-data , i wanted to add tide-data1 with different col names

Comment: Modified the answer to reflect your changes to your OP. If you would supply a minimal example (including creation of 10 rows of your data frame), it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: after first groupby it acting as list after adding second one it returning error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Can you correct the Answer Still I cant able to solve it Same error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'