# How to convert a pandas data frame to nested json

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently have a data frame contain laptop info and the aim is to transform the data to a nested json structure. As the laptop's brand, price and weight are related info, thus would like to group them together under the laptop field. Any pointer on how to convert the data frame would be appreciated.

*`data frame`*

[image]

*`Target json structure`*

[image]

Comment: Similar question and answer you can find here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470954/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470954/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json)

Comment: Please don't post images. Images are discouraged on SO. Please take time to read [`how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `df`:

```
In [2729]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Store code':[1, 12, 132], 'Laptop brand':['Lenovo', 'Apple', 'HP'], 'Laptop price':[1000, 2000, 1200], 'Laptop weight':[1.2, 1.5, 1.4], 'star':[3, 5, 4]})

In [2730]: df
Out[2730]: 
   Store code Laptop brand  Laptop price  Laptop weight  star
0           1       Lenovo          1000            1.2     3
1          12        Apple          2000            1.5     5
2         132           HP          1200            1.4     4
```

Use [`df._to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='records'`:

```
In [2734]: x = df.to_dict('records') # Create a list of dicts from df
In [2738]: l = [] # Empty list for storing your output

In [2763]: for i in x: # Iterate every item in list of dicts
      ...:     d = {}
      ...:     d1 = {}
      ...:     for k,v in i.items(): # Iterate each individual dict
      ...:         if 'Laptop' in k: # Check if word `Laptop` is present in key 
      ...:             d1[k] = v     # If yes, create a separate dict for all laptop keys
      ...:         else:
      ...:             d[k] = v      
      ...:     d['Laptop'] = [d1]    # Add another key `Laptop` which holds a `list` of dicts of Laptop
      ...:     l.append(d)           # Append this dict in list
      ...:
```

**Output:**

```
In [2774]: print(json.dumps(l, indent=2))
[
  {
    "Store code": 1,
    "star": 3,
    "Laptop": [
      {
        "Laptop brand": "Lenovo",
        "Laptop price": 1000,
        "Laptop weight": 1.2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Store code": 12,
    "star": 5,
    "Laptop": [
      {
        "Laptop brand": "Apple",
        "Laptop price": 2000,
        "Laptop weight": 1.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Store code": 132,
    "star": 4,
    "Laptop": [
      {
        "Laptop brand": "HP",
        "Laptop price": 1200,
        "Laptop weight": 1.4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you, it'd be great if you could add some explanation

Comment: You're welcome. I've added explanation in form of comments in my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: thank you. May i ask you've checked if word `Laptop` is present in key, so if the key doesnt contain the word 'Laptop', is there a way to include the key to the separate dict?

Comment: If the key does not contain the word `Laptop`, it will be stored in the same way, like `Store code` and `star`.

Comment: okay got it, if in the future, there's a new key that doesn't contain the word Laptop yet need to be included in the separate dict 'Laptop', could this be done?

Comment: Yes, it can. You would need to tweak the `if` statement in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226569/discussion-between-codezzz-and-mayank-porwal).