# Converting SQL table to nested JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have rows like this in my snowflake database:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| Foo | Bar | Baz |
+-----+-----+-----+
| A   | a   | []  |
| A   | b   | []  |
| B   | a   | []  |
| B   | b   | []  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to convert this into:

```
  "A": {
    "a": [],
    "b": []
  },
  "B": {
    "a": [],
    "b": []
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake allows to achieve the desired effect with SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t
AS
SELECT 'A' AS foo, 'a' AS bar, PARSE_JSON('[]') AS Baz
UNION ALL SELECT 'A' AS foo, 'b' AS bar, PARSE_JSON('[]') AS Baz
UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS foo, 'a' AS bar, PARSE_JSON('[]') AS Baz
UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS foo, 'b' AS bar, PARSE_JSON('[]') AS Baz;


SELECT OBJECT_AGG(foo, s) AS result
FROM (SELECT foo, OBJECT_AGG(bar, baz) AS s
      FROM t
      GROUP BY foo) sub;
```

Output:

```
{
  "A": {
    "a": [],
    "b": []
  },
  "B": {
    "a": [],
    "b": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pandas to read sql data and convert it to nested json

Refer to [Convert Pandas Dataframe to nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470954/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json)

Comment: I would like to keep it as SQL

Comment: @maxisme - ok ! Please update the question title and also add details about DB & your requirement as well