# Fastest way to generate a nested JSON using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is a sample of a real-world problem that I cannot find a way to solve.

I need to create a nested JSON from a pandas dataframe. Considering [this data](https://www.kaggle.com/rubenssjr/brasilian-houses-to-rent/version/2?select=houses_to_rent_v2.csv), I need to create a `JSON` object like that:

```json
[
  {
    "city": "Belo Horizonte",
    "by_rooms": [
      {
        "rooms": 1,
        "total price": [
          {
            "total (R$)": 499,
            "details": [
              {
                "animal": "acept",
                "area": 22,
                "bathroom": 1,
                "parking spaces": 0,
                "furniture": "not furnished",
                "hoa (R$)": 30,
                "rent amount (R$)": 450,
                "property tax (R$)": 13,
                "fire insurance (R$)": 6
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "rooms": 2,
        "total price": [
          {
            "total (R$)": 678,
            "details": [
              {
                "animal": "not acept",
                "area": 50,
                "bathroom": 1,
                "parking spaces": 0,
                "furniture": "not furnished",
                "hoa (R$)": 0,
                "rent amount (R$)": 644,
                "property tax (R$)": 25,
                "fire insurance (R$)": 9
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Campinas",
    "by_rooms": [
      {
        "rooms": 1,
        "total price": [
          {
            "total (R$)": 711,
            "details": [
              {
                "animal": "acept",
                "area": 42,
                "bathroom": 1,
                "parking spaces": 0,
                "furniture": "not furnished",
                "hoa (R$)": 0,
                "rent amount (R$)": 690,
                "property tax (R$)": 12,
                "fire insurance (R$)": 9
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

each level can have one or more items.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470954/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json), I have a snippet like that:

```python
data = pd.read_csv("./houses_to_rent_v2.csv")
    cols = data.columns
    data = (
        data.groupby(['city', 'rooms', 'total (R$)'])[['animal', 'area', 'bathroom', 'parking spaces', 'furniture',
                                                       'hoa (R$)', 'rent amount (R$)', 'property tax (R$)', 'fire insurance (R$)']]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))
        .reset_index(name='details')
        .groupby(['city', 'rooms'])[['total (R$)', 'details']]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))
        .reset_index(name='total price')
        .groupby(['city'])[['rooms', 'total price']]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))
        .reset_index(name='by_rooms')
    )

    data.to_json('./jsondata.json', orient='records', force_ascii=False)
```

but all those `groupby`s don't look very Pythonic and it's pretty slow.

Before use this method, I tried split this big dataframe into smaller ones to use individual `groupby`s for each level, but it's even slower than doing that way.

I tried `dask`, with no improvement at all.

I read about numba and cython, but I have no idea how to implement in this case. All docs that I find use only numeric data and I have string and date/datetime data too.

In my real-world problem, this data is processed to response to http request. My dataframe has 30+ columns and ~35K rows per request and it takes 45 seconds to process just this snippet.

So, there is a faster way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as **list** / **dict** comprehensions.  Have not timed this, but I'm not waiting for it.

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib

# fmt: off
# download data set
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/rubenssjr/brasilian-houses-to-rent"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
dfs = {f.filename: pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist()}
# fmt: on

js = [
    {
        "city": g[0],
        "by_room": [
            {
                "rooms": r["rooms"],
                "total_price": [
                    {
                        "total (R$)": r["total (R$)"],
                        "details": [
                            {
                                k: v
                                for k, v in r.items()
                                if k not in ["city", "rooms", "total (R$)"]
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            }
            for r in g[1].to_dict("records")
        ],
    }
    for g in dfs["houses_to_rent_v2.csv"].groupby("city")
]

print(len(js), len(js[0]["by_room"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to adapt @RobRaymond answer, because I need the inner data grouped too. So I take his code, did some adjustments and this is the final result:

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib

# fmt: off
# download data set
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/rubenssjr/brasilian-houses-to-rent"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
dfs = {f.filename: pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist()}
# fmt: on

js = [
    {
        "city": g[0],
        "by_room": [
            {
                "rooms": r["rooms"],
                "total_price": [
                    {
                        "total (R$)": r["total (R$)"],
                        "details": [
                            {
                                k: v
                                for k, v in r.items()
                                if k not in ["city", "rooms", "total (R$)"]
                            }
                        ],
                     }
                ],
            }
            for r in g[1].to_dict("records")
        ],
    }
    for g in dfs["houses_to_rent_v2.csv"].groupby("city")
]

for city in js:
    rooms_qty = list(set([r['rooms'] for r in city['by_room']]))
    newRooms = [{'rooms': x, 'total_price': []} for x in rooms_qty]
    for r in city['by_room']:
      newRooms[rooms_qty.index(r['rooms'])]'total_price'].extend(r['total_price'])
        for r in newRooms:
            prices = list(set([p['total (R$)'] for p in r['total_price']]))
            newPrices = [{'total (R$)': x, 'details': []} for x in prices]
            for price in r['total_price']:
                newPrices[prices.index(price['total (R$)'])]['details'].extend(price['details'])

        r['total_price'] = newPrices

    city['by_room'] = newRooms
```

And the execution time drops to 5 seconds.