# Create nested dictionary from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this table:

| Team | X or Y | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 80% |
| A | Y | 20% |
| B | X | 70% |
| B | Y | 30% |
| C | X | 60% |
| C | Y | 40% |

I want to create a nested dictionary out of this so that if I input the team name and input X or Y, I get the percentage as a return value.

In Python I used the .tolist() method to create lists out of each individual column.

My initial strategy was to create a dict out of the second two columns `dict_1 = dict(zip(list2, list3))` and then `dict_2 = dict(zip(list1, dict_1))` but that didn't work out because column "X or Y", for example, has similar values, and dictionary keys cannot have repeated values.

The output I had in mind was

```
{'A':{'X':80%, 'Y':20%}, 'B':{'X':70%,'Y':30%}, ...}
```

How would I create this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='Team', index='X or Y', values='Percentage').to_dict()
{'A': {'X': '80%', 'Y': '20%'}, 'B': {'X': '70%', 'Y': '30%'}, 'C': {'X': '60%', 'Y': '40%'}}
```

Comment: This is a great answer and should be accepted imo.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest method for this task is to iterate over the dataframe using `itertuples()` and create the dictionary on the fly.

```py
result = {}
for Team, XorY, Percentage in df.itertuples(index=False):
    result.setdefault(Team, {})[XorY] = Percentage
```

where `result` now becomes the expected:

```
{'A': {'X': '80%', 'Y': '20%'},
 'B': {'X': '70%', 'Y': '30%'},
 'C': {'X': '60%', 'Y': '40%'}}
```

A more "pandas" code could be to call `to_dict` in groupby:

```py
result = (
    df.groupby('Team')
    .apply(lambda g: g.set_index('X or Y')['Percentage'].to_dict())
    .to_dict()
)
```

This is however slower than `itertuples` loop.

Not quite the same but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780569/19123103) also constructs a nested object from a dataframe and includes a benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

A possible solution, which uses [`pandas.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) followed by [`pandas.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
(df.set_index(['Team', 'X or Y'])
.stack().droplevel(2).unstack('X or Y').T.to_dict())
```

@cottontail suggests, in a comment below, a shorter and more efficient version of this solution:

```
df.set_index(['Team', 'X or Y'])['Percentage'].unstack('Team').to_dict()
```

---

**Solution 2**

Another possible solution, which uses [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) to construct the dictionary:

```
(df.groupby('Team').apply(lambda x: 
    {'X': x.loc[x['X or Y'].eq('X'), 'Percentage'].iloc[0], 
     'Y': x.loc[x['X or Y'].eq('Y'), 'Percentage'].iloc[0]})
.to_dict())
```

---

**Output**

```
{'A': {'X': '80%', 'Y': '20%'},
 'B': {'X': '70%', 'Y': '30%'},
 'C': {'X': '60%', 'Y': '40%'}}
```

Comment: You can do Solution 1 in fewer number of method calls if you `unstack` instead of `stack`: `df.set_index(['Team', 'X or Y'])['Percentage'].unstack('Team').to_dict()`. In any case, this is a nice answer.

Comment: Excellent idea, @cottontail! Thanks for having shared that with me!

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the all columns (with `zip()` func):

```
nd = {}  # nested dict
for team, xy, percentage in zip(data['Team'], data['X or Y'], data['Percentage']):
    if team not in nd:
        nd[team] = {}
    nd[team][xy] = percentage
```

Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'X or Y': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
    'Percentage': ['80%', '20%', '70%', '30%', '60%', '40%']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)

nd = {}  # nested dict
for team, xy, percentage in zip(data['Team'], data['X or Y'], data['Percentage']):
    if team not in nd:
        nd[team] = {}
    nd[team][xy] = percentage
print(nd)
```

DF and Nested Dict Output:

```
  Team X or Y Percentage
0    A      X        80%
1    A      Y        20%
2    B      X        70%
3    B      Y        30%
4    C      X        60%
5    C      Y        40%
{'A': {'X': '80%', 'Y': '20%'}, 'B': {'X': '70%', 'Y': '30%'}, 'C': {'X': '60%', 'Y': '40%'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to your end goal, that you want to "input the team name and input X or Y, [and] get the percentage as a return value", but the output would look different than what you suggested above. If that doesn't work for you, please ignore this answer.

I'd re-index the table to have the inputs as indices, and then get the dictionary from there, so:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'X or Y': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
    'Percentage': ['80%', '20%', '70%', '30%', '60%', '40%']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.set_index(['Team', 'X or Y'])
df1.to_dict()

{'Percentage': {('A', 'X'): '80%', ('A', 'Y'): '20%', ('B', 'X'): '70%', ('B', 'Y'): '30%', ('C', 'X'): '60%', ('C', 'Y'): '40%'}}
```