# Pandas MultiIndex (more than 2 levels) DataFrame to Nested Dict/JSON

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920624/convert-pandas-multiindex-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary), but I want to take it a step further. Is it possible to extend the solution to work with more levels? Multilevel dataframes' `.to_dict()` method has some promising options, but most of them will return entries that are indexed by tuples (i.e. `(A, 0, 0): 274.0`) rather than nesting them in dictionaries.

For an example of what I'm looking to accomplish, consider this multiindex dataframe:

```
data = {0: {
        ('A', 0, 0): 274.0, 
        ('A', 0, 1): 19.0, 
        ('A', 1, 0): 67.0, 
        ('A', 1, 1): 12.0, 
        ('B', 0, 0): 83.0, 
        ('B', 0, 1): 45.0
    },
    1: {
        ('A', 0, 0): 254.0, 
        ('A', 0, 1): 11.0, 
        ('A', 1, 0): 58.0, 
        ('A', 1, 1): 11.0, 
        ('B', 0, 0): 76.0, 
        ('B', 0, 1): 56.0
    }   
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.index = ['entry1', 'entry2']
df
# output:

         A                              B
         0              1               0
         0      1       0       1       0       1
entry1   274.0  19.0    67.0    12.0    83.0    45.0
entry2   254.0  11.0    58.0    11.0    76.0    56.0
```

You can imagine that we have many records here, not just two, and that the index names could be longer strings. How could you turn this into nested dictionaries (or directly to JSON) that look like this:

```
[
 {'entry1': {'A': {0: {0: 274.0, 1: 19.0}, 1: {0: 67.0, 1: 12.0}},
  'B': {0: {0: 83.0, 1: 45.0}}},
 'entry2': {'A': {0: {0: 254.0, 1: 11.0}, 1: {0: 58.0, 1: 11.0}},
  'B': {0: {0: 76.0, 1: 56.0}}}}
]
```

I'm thinking some amount of recursion could potentially be helpful, maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798112/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dict/19900276#19900276), but have so far been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, you really need to do 2 things here:

- `df.to_dict()`
- Convert this to nested dictionary.

`df.to_dict(orient='index')` gives you a dictionary with the index as keys; it looks like this:

```
>>> df.to_dict(orient='index')
{'entry1': {('A', 0, 0): 274.0,
  ('A', 0, 1): 19.0,
  ('A', 1, 0): 67.0,
  ('A', 1, 1): 12.0,
  ('B', 0, 0): 83.0,
  ('B', 0, 1): 45.0},
 'entry2': {('A', 0, 0): 254.0,
  ('A', 0, 1): 11.0,
  ('A', 1, 0): 58.0,
  ('A', 1, 1): 11.0,
  ('B', 0, 0): 76.0,
  ('B', 0, 1): 56.0}}
```

Now you need to nest this.  Here's a trick [from Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932879/7954504) to do that:

```
def nest(d: dict) -> dict:
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        target = result
        for k in key[:-1]:  # traverse all keys but the last
            target = target.setdefault(k, {})
        target[key[-1]] = value
    return result
```

Putting this all together:

```
def df_to_nested_dict(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    d = df.to_dict(orient='index')
    return {k: nest(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
>>> df_to_nested_dict(df)
{'entry1': {'A': {0: {0: 274.0, 1: 19.0}, 1: {0: 67.0, 1: 12.0}},
  'B': {0: {0: 83.0, 1: 45.0}}},
 'entry2': {'A': {0: {0: 254.0, 1: 11.0}, 1: {0: 58.0, 1: 11.0}},
  'B': {0: {0: 76.0, 1: 56.0}}}}
```

Comment: For using type hints you get +1 :)

Comment: Nice, very clean answer! It's unfortunate that Pandas doesn't have a way of doing this that does not involve manually iterating through every row

Answer (score 0):

I took the idea from the previous answer and slightly modified it.

1) Took the function nested_dict from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348345/declaring-a-multi-dimensional-dictionary-in-python), to create the dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
def nested_dict(n, type):
    if n == 1:
        return defaultdict(type)
    else:
        return defaultdict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))
```

2 Wrote the following function:

> ```
> def df_to_nested_dict(self, df, type):
>
>     # Get the number of levels
>     temp = df.index.names
>     lvl = len(temp)
>
>     # Create the target dictionary
>     new_nested_dict=nested_dict(lvl, type)
>     # Convert the dataframe to a dictionary
>     temp_dict = df.to_dict(orient='index')
>     for x, y in temp_dict.items():
>         dict_keys = ''
>         # Process the individual items from the key
>         for item in x:
>             dkey = '[%d]' % item
>             dict_keys = dict_keys + dkey
>
>         # Create a string and execute it
>         dict_update = 'new_nested_dict%s = y' % dict_keys
>         exec(dict_update)
>
>     return new_nested_dict
> ```

It is the same idea but it is done slightly different