# python collections.defaultdict on assignment but not on lookup

Tags: python, data-structures

I have the following code:

```
from collections import *
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
data = nested_dict()
```

which enables me to write any new "path" in the dict as a one liner:

```
data['A']['B']['C']=3
```

which is what I want.
But I want to get an exception when running (for any non existing path):

```
var = data['A']['XXX']['C']
```

I feel I need defaultdict when writing, plain dict when reading...

Or, is there a simple nice way to check if a 'path' exists in a defaultdict without modifying its contents...

I tried converting the defaultdict back to a dict before the lookup, hoping that:

```
dict(data)['A']['XXX']['C']
```

would raise a exception... but it kept creating missing keys...

Comment: `dict(data)` is a *shallow* copy.

Comment: None of the objects involved have any way to distinguish between `var = data['A']['XXX']['C']`, which you want an exception for, and the first steps of `data['A']['XXX']['C']['D'] = 4`, which shouldn't throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distingsuish between lookups and writes here, because it is the *lookups* that create your intermediary structure in the `data['A']['B']['C'] = 3` assignment. Python executes the indexing operations `data['A']` and then `['B']` first, before assigning to the `'C'` key. The `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__missing__` hooks involved to make that work are not given enough context to distinguish between access that then leads to the `'C'` assignment from only 'reading' `'XXX'` in your second example.

You really only have 3 options here:

- Don't use `defaultdict`. When writing, *explicitly* create new nested dictionaries with [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead; you can chain these calls as needed:

  ```
  var = {}
  var.setdefault('A', {}).setdefault('B', {})['C'] = 3
  ```

  or you can [wrap recursive behaviour in a few functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932755/arbitrarily-nested-dictionary-from-tuples/50932879#50932879).
- Create a recursive copy of your `defaultdict` structure to replace it with a `dict` structure once you are done writing:

  ```
  def dd_to_d(dd):
      r = {}
      stack = [(r, dd)]
      while stack:
          target, dd = stack.pop()
          for key, value in dd.items():
              if isinstance(value, defaultdict):
                  sub = {}
                  stack.append((sub, value))
                  value = sub
              target[key] = value
      return r

  var = dd_to_d(var)
  ```
- Set all the `default_factory` attributes to `None` to disable creating new values for missing keys:

  ```
  def disable_dd(dd):
      stack = [dd]
      while stack:
          dd = stack.pop()
          dd.default_factory = None
          for key, value in dd.items():
              if isinstance(value, defaultdict):
                  stack.append(value)

  disable_dd(var)
  ```

Comment: Thx. this are just work around... But maybe the problem has no better solution. I'll mark the answer as usefull (to give your effort credits), but leave room for a final solution if ever someone comes with a nicer proposal.

Comment: @user1159290: I'd not call this a work-around. If you are using defaultdict, then your only options are to copy the structure over to dictionaries or disable the factory. The alternative option is to not use defaultdict, with `dict` being the obvious choice in that case.

Comment: ok. no-one having any better solution to suggest, I have accepted your 'solution'. But really that is  not as good as I had hope for (but maybe best). In my case multiple assignments and lookups are interleaved,which makes none of the proposed 'solutions' look nice.

Comment: @user1159290: I realised I didn't quite explain why these were your options. I've added that to the answer now.

Comment: @matijnp : thx. I realized what happened (lookups being done during the assignment) when it happened, of course, but still hoped something I did not know of could be done towards a better solution. Thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

An obvious solution is to just use plain dicts with a function that can "materialize" the intermediate keys:

```
def write_path(d, path, value):
    for key in path[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(key, {})
    d[path[-1]] = value

d = {}

write_path(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3)
print(d)
print(d['a']['b']['c'])
print(d['a']['b']['d'])
```

outputs

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 3}}}
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writedefaultdict.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(d['a']['b']['d'])
KeyError: 'd'
```

Comment: Same here. not a real solution but surely an obvious possible work-around. (+1)