# How to convert aggregated table to json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, aggregate-functions

I was trying to apply group by function and convert the dataframe to json.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[11, 'Rondonia', 3,'Alta Floresta'], [11, 'Rondonia', 4,'Cacoal'],[11, 'Rondonia', 5,'Caxibi']]),
                   columns=['uf','nome_uf' ,'municipio', 'nome_municipio'])
df2 

uf  nome_uf municipio   nome_municipio
0   11  Rondonia    3   Alta Floresta
1   11  Rondonia    4   Cacoal
2   11  Rondonia    5   Caxibi
```

```
df2.groupby(['uf','nome_uf','municipio','nome_municipio']).count()

uf  nome_uf municipio   nome_municipio
11  Rondonia    3   Alta Floresta
                4   Cacoal
                5   Caxibi
```

I would like to convert this kind of table with levels to json, keeping the hierarchies. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas MultiIndex (more than 2 levels) DataFrame to Nested Dict/JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929768/pandas-multiindex-more-than-2-levels-dataframe-to-nested-dict-json)

Comment: I will take a look, thank you!

Comment: It didn't work for me!