# Python Pandas Multi Indexing by keyword

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

if I have a multi-index data frame in pandas like this.

```
test.index.names
FrozenList(['target', 'h', 'd', 'y', 'obsrv'])

test.index.values
('A', '15', '60', '0', 97),
('B', '15', '60', '0', 98),
```

I can index the data frame associated with target = A, h = 15, d = 60, y = 0, obrv = 97 by using a tuple like this

```
test.loc[('A', '15', '60', '0', 97)]
```

But I want to index this data frame somehow like this.

> test(target = 'A', h = 15)...

such that the order inside does not matter. Is that possible ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loc you can use .xs() to get cross sections with the index intact. Not exactly the form you're looking for, but should serve your purposes I'm guessing:

```
test.xs(('A', '15', '60', '0', 97), level=('target', 'h', 'd', 'y', 'obsrv'))
```

You could then use the answer provided in [DataFrame with MultiIndex to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39074579/7619676) to convert to a dict.

I can give a more specific answer for your problem if you can provide a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For [multiple index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

```
test.loc[pd.IndexSlice['A', '15',:,:,:],:]
```